# clean up object lead to lost of 0 value

Tags: javascript

I came across a list of data operations and lost value of [0].

I could not find out why. it's good if I change value to [1], but if i put value [0], then it's gone.

Here is the code:

```
let data = {
  title:"hello world",
  value: [0]
}
let sanitized = removeNull(data);
console.log(sanitized)

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
function removeNull(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k =>
      (obj[k] && typeof obj[k] === 'object') && removeNull(obj[k]) ||
      (typeof obj[k] !== 'boolean' && !obj[k] && obj[k] !== undefined) && delete obj[k]
  );
  return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `obj[k]` is `0`, `delete obj[k]` is being executed because in the expression:

```
(obj[k] && typeof obj[k] === 'object') && removeNull(obj[k]) ||
      (typeof obj[k] !== 'boolean' && !obj[k] && obj[k] !== undefined) && delete obj[k]
```

...`obj[k]` is falsey (so the entire top line above is false.  Then we proceed to check the second line because of the ||.

- `typeof 0` is `Number` which is `!== boolean`, so that's true...
- `!0` is truthy...
- `0 !== undefined` is also true...

which leaves us to check the truthiness of the final term which is `delete obj[k]`.  ...which happens to be `true` by the way, not that it matters, because `0` gets deleted by virtue of us even checking that last term's value.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Ahhh,`typeof obj[k] !== 'boolean' && !obj[k] && obj[k] !== undefined` evaluates to true because `0` is considered falsy in Javascript.  So `!obj[k]` is true.

### Original answer

The current removeEmpty function is testing if the result of `JSON.stringify(o[k] === "[0]")` is truthy.  You probably meant to test if the stringified contents of o[k] are equal to "[0]".  So something like `JSON.stringify(o[k]) === "[0]"` should solve your problem.

Comment: sorry I updated my question, i remove this removeEmpty function but still get the wrong result. so I think it's not removeEmpty function issue.

Comment: thanks, but i still not get why the 0 value is gone after this function.

Answer (score 1):

Some key concepts:

- `0` is falsey
- `typeof null === 'object'` is true
- `typeof [] === 'object'` is true

Currently, the code executes as follows:

- When you get to the part of the loop where `obj[k]` = `[0]`, removeNull() gets called on `[0]` because arrays are of type `object`.
- When we iterate over `[0]` in that call of removeNull(), `k` starts as `0` (the index in the array), and `obj[k]` becomes `0` (the value). `0` passes `typeof 0 !== 'boolean' && !0 && 0 !== undefined`, so it gets `deleted` and turned into an empty item in the array. `delete` empties out array elements but doesn't remove the index.

There might be some ways to reorganize the code to make it a little safer and easier to debug, depending on whether you want to remove null in arrays, too.

```
let data = {
  title:"hello world", // not removed
  value: [
    0, // not removed
    null // removed
  ],
  name: null, // removed
  author: {
    name: null, // removed
    hats: false, // not removed
    pets: [null] // --> []
    partners: [] // --> []
  }
}
const sanitized = removeNull(data);
console.log(sanitized)

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

function removeNull(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if(obj[key] === null) {
      // removes the element differently
      // depending on whether obj is array or object.
      return Array.isArray(obj) ? obj.splice(key, 1) : delete obj[key]
    }
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') removeNull(obj[key])
  })
  return obj
}
```

If you don't care about checking for `null` in arrays, add `&& !Array.isArray(obj)` to the second check, and remove the ternary that decides how to delete.

One note: in addition to returning the new null-less object, this code (and your code) currently also modify the original object.